# Pagination and search issue in table

Tags: angularjs, pagination

Tried to do adaptive variant of table but when I use search, records don't `toggle`. And tried to use `dirPagination` for pagination but it breaks the table. What can you advice to fix the toggle after search and simple way how to do pagination? And how to rename options in sort select (and not to break sorting)? Here's my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Qk4AxzXLuDDAAXt3wZ6z?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

use blew link it's may be help  demo 
http://code.ciphertrick.com/demo/search-sort-pagination/

Link for download
http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/06/01/search-sort-and-pagination-ngrepeat-angularjs/

Comment: I saw this guide on youtube and when I add pagination it doesn't appear in DOM.

Comment: please download second link there is ready demo, download from there and add in your local and try will help you 

80% same as your code

Comment: thanks :) It's strange... I did the same but pagination didn't added)